# How to pass python list to javascript array using Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, templates

UPDATE 7/23/2020

I have a Django project where I am trying to pass a list of values from a python function to my 'index.html' file. This list of values comes from a DB query in my views.py file

my views.py

```
def index_view(request):
    
    context = {}


    con=sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    cursor=con.cursor()

    db_query="SELECT distinct product_name from dboinvproduct"

    cursor.execute(db_query)

    result=cursor.fetchall()

    con.close()

    list_of_products = list(itertools.chain(*result)) 
    
    context['product_names'] = list_of_products
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

then within the body of my index.html

```
function loadFunct(){
               var products = "{{product_names|safe}}";
               alert(products);
              }
```

And the alert shows the following string:

```
['product a', 'product b', 'product c', 'product d']
```

Which is much closer than I was previously. The problem is, this is a string that looks like an array... Which means this will not work for my application... I need it to be in the form of an array.

What is the best way to do this? I have read about json_dumps on the python side, but I get a typeError because that expects a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps()` should accept list like this.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['a','b'])
'["a", "b"]'
```

Therefore you can pre-jsonify the list in the view like this,

```
context['product_names'] = json.dumps(list_of_products)
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and use in the template like this.

```
function loadFunct(){
    var products = {{product_names|safe}}; // Be aware that there are no quotes or double quotes. 
    console.log(products);
}
```

Comment: Thanks user3003464, that worked! This feature is now fully functional. Very pleased!